# Is my proof in calculus correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

My Math professor asked me to prove a theorem in Calculus.
After some thinking, I came up with a simple proof, but I’m not sure if it's correct.

---

**The Challenge**

Given $X^i = (X^i_1,\dots,X^i_n)$, prove the following theorem:
 $$\text{If } X^k \to X \text{ then } X^k_j \to\ X_j \text{ for every }\ j = 1,2,\dots,n. $$

---

**My proof**

1. If $  X^k \to X$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall k \geq  n$, $\|X^k-X\| < \epsilon$.
2. Let us assume there's some $j$ for which $X^k_j \to\ X_j$ is false.
3. It follows that $X^k - X = (0,0,\dots,A,0,\dots,0)$ where $A = |X^k_j -
    X_j|$.
4. $|X^k - X| = \sqrt{0^2+0^2+\dots+A^2+0^2+\dots+0^2} = \sqrt{A^2} = A$.
5. $ A > \epsilon$.
6. From stages 4 and 5, it follows that $\|X^k-X\| > \epsilon$. Contradiction!
7. Therefore, $X^k_j \to X_j$ Q.E.D.

[My proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCs1n.jpg)

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it right now. Thanks

Comment: Next time, please type *only the math* with MathJax. It's much easier for everyone to have the text normally!

Comment: All right, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

A straight forward proof is

If $ Xk→X$ then, $ ∀ϵ>0∃n∈N$ so that $∀k≥n, ∥Xk−X∥<ϵ.$

Note that for every j,we have
$$|Xkj−Xj|\le ∥Xk−X∥<ϵ.$$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm glad to hear it

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

This might come in handy. If $X$ is a vector, you have
$$|X_k| \le \|X\|, \qquad 1 \le k \le n.$$